# how to take the contents of 2 arraylist thats in a single method

Tags: java

i am using wornet3.0 for getting synonyms and the gloss for each word....i have attachted a piece of my code(a searchword method) where i have 2 arraylist....i need to return the 2 arraylist for remaining operations....how can i do that ? i tried to use map...but still i dont have any  unique key  to do so.....anyone give me some idea how can i get the content of both the array list (nums and nums1)

```
public ArrayList<String> searchWord(String key)
    {

    nums.clear();   
            /*  A word is having a different WordId in different synsets. Each Word is having a
         *  unique Index.  
        */

        //Get  the index associated with the word, 'book' with Parts of Speech NOUN.

        IIndexWord idxWord = idict.getIndexWord(key, POS.NOUN);
         if(idxWord==null)
                 {
                     return nums;
                 }
        System.out.println("Word ->"+key);
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println("-------------");

        int i=1;

        /*getWordIDs() returns all the WordID associated with a index 
         * 
         */ 
                IWord word;
                ISynset wordSynset = null;
                //if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(idxWord.getWordIDs()))
        for(IWordID wordID : idxWord.getWordIDs())
        {
            //Construct an IWord object representing word associated with wordID  
            word = idict.getWord(wordID);
            //System.out.println("SENSE->"+i);
            //System.out.println("---------");

                wordSynset = word.getSynset();

            System.out.print("Synset "+i+" {");

            //Returns all the words present in the synset wordSynset
            for(IWord synonym : wordSynset.getWords())
            {
                System.out.print(synonym.getLemma()+", ");
                                nums1.add(synonym.getLemma());
            }
            System.out.print("}"+"\n");

            nums.add(wordSynset.getGloss());
                        for(String s:nums)
//                      {
//                          System.out.print(s);
//                      }
            //Returns the gloss associated with the synset.
            System.out.println("GLOSS -> "+wordSynset.getGloss());

            System.out.println();
            i++;
                }
                        return nums;



                 //   WordNetDatabase database=WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object holding/wrapping your two `ArrayList`s:

```
public Something searchWord(final String key) {
    // ...
    return new Something(num1, num2);
}
```

with:

```
public class Something {
    private ArrayList<String> num;
    private ArrayList<String> num1;

    public Something(final List<String> num, final List<String> num1) {
        this.num = num;
        this.num1 = num1;
    }

    // getters, setters, ...
}
```

**or**

use [`Pair`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) from Apache commons-lang:

```
public Pair<List<String>, List<String>> searchWord(final String key) {
    // ...
    return new Pair<List<String>, List<String>>(num1, num2);
}
```

Comment: when i use  pair....there is an error in the coding...read line on pair...(i am working on netbeans.....it askes to create a class for pair)....wat to do now????

Comment: i have done with pair...but now how to get the arraylist from the return?

Comment: you need to add commons-lang to your classpath. To get back elements use `left()` and `right()` (see the linked javadoc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if what you want is **to return TWO ArrayLists**, you can simply define a class that contains two ArrayLists as instance variables. At the end of your searchWord method, create a new instance of this custom class and set its two ArrayLists to be nums and nums1. And then change your searchWord method to return this new class. As long as you write your custom class the way you want to, it should be easy to access the contents of both ArrayLists after returning them.

Comment: in tried it...but that is not possible for this process...can u afford me some other idea